# Security for these tasks, 'Create Fiscal Summary Schedule' and 'Edit Fiscal Summary Schedule' in Workday

Tags: security, workday-api

I am trying to give security to these tasks, 'Create Fiscal Summary Schedule' and 'Edit Fiscal Summary Schedule' to one of my business users. I am not sure on which Domain this comes under? Are there any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the View Security for Securable Item task to see what domain they are tied to.